# How do to convert an array string in php

Tags: php

I have a variable `$object` like this :

`$object = ['Apple-2','Apolo-23','Nine-99','Ex-0'];`

How do to make each value in $object to array. I want output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple-2,
    [1] => Apolo-23,
    [2] => Nine-99,
    [3] => Ex-0
)
```

Comment: Is the `$object` a string? because I dont see any quotes

Comment: If that `$object` is a string u may use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to do it but of course you have to cut off extra characters that wrapped it

Comment: @gitguddoge yes, $object is a string, sorry i will update my question

Comment: Ermmm you can just simply `$object = array('Apple-2','Apolo-23','Nine-99','Ex-0');` that i assume you can change that line of code?

Comment: @gitguddoge, what is delimeter i put in explode? a comma?

Comment: can you change the way you assign the `$object` value or you must assign in that way? (btw that `$object` is already an array by itself...)

Comment: @gitguddoge i must assign in that way

Comment: this is just an assumption, are you trying to print because you want to debug?
just echo "<pre>"; print_r($object); i hope this is what you mean, cuz basically your array is an array of string, and supposedly value of that is the one you put below but of course with 'Apple-2 '  not Apple-2

Comment: $object is an array itself.

Comment: you can explode it and assign in new array using foreach

Comment: @RopAliMunshi is right, in this case I think the question title is a bit confusing. there shouldn't be a convert but how to print

Comment: @RahmatEffendi you have to tell us exactly what your variable holds? An array or a string? In both cases you can check my answer to get help

Answer (score 3):

`$object` is already an array.
You just need to print it.

```
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($object);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output :**

[image]

if need comma after each value, add below line before print:

```
array_walk($object, function(&$object) {
    $object = $object . ",";
    return $object;
});
```

Comment: show your out so OP can match with it

Comment: where is comma behind first element i.e [0]=>Apple-2,

Comment: Ohh. Is it really required? or it's just by mistaken?

Comment: I have added array_walk if it is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_decode`:

```php
json_decode(str_replace("'", '"', $object));
```